# High School Geometry: Prove $DE = BC\tan x \tan y$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given the figure below with angles ∠DAC and ∠BAE both 90 degrees, prove that

$$DE = BC\tan x\tan y$$

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. looks you forgot to put the question... All i see is what you've tried, but the actual problem statement is missing

Comment: Updated; the problem statement is just that shown in the title.

Comment: Oh ok... forgive me but what's the given info? How did you get $\angle D = 90-y$ ?

Comment: Geez my apologies it has been a long day; we are only given that angles DAC and BAE are both equal to 90 degrees; that's the only condition specified by the problem.

Comment: That's fine haha. Now the question makes sense thanks!

Comment: $AF$ perpendicular to $DE$ intersecting $DE$ at $F$, solve using similar triangles.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From the right triangles ADC and AEB,

$$\tan x \tan y =\frac {AE}{AB}\frac {AD}{AC}\tag{1}$$

Recognize $\sin \angle BAC = \sin (x+y)$ and apply the sine rule to the triangle ABC,

$$\sin x = \frac{AC}{BC}\sin (x+y), \>\>\>\>\>\sin y =\frac{AB}{BC} \sin (x+y)\tag{2}$$

Recognize $\sin\angle E = \cos x$,  $\sin\angle D = \cos y$, $\sin \angle DAE = \sin (x+y)$, and apply the sine rule to the triangles ADC,

$$\cos x= \frac{AD}{DE}\sin (x+y) , \>\>\>\>\>\cos y = \frac{AE}{DE}\sin (x+y)\tag{3}$$

Combine (2) and (3), and then substitute (1) to get

$$\tan^2 x \tan^2 y =\frac{DE^2}{BC^2}$$

Thus,

$$DE = BC\tan x \tan y $$

Answer (score 0):

You can work it by using just tanx = opp/adj :

[image]